# Why is this function not visible in this other function?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use a function inside another function. Right now, `setPanodatas()` appears as not defined:

```
function setPoints(obj, prop) {
  // Some code
  if (unzippedNewPanodatas)
    unzippedNewPanodatas =    unzippedNewPanodatas.slice(scope.panodatas.length)

  _.each(unzippedNewPanodatas, function(point) {
    var Panodata = AV.Object.extend('PanoramaData')
    var panodata = new Panodata()
    obj[prop].push(setPanodatas(panodata.toJSON(), point))
  })
}

function setPanodata(panodata, point) {
  panodata.set('index', point.index)
  panodata.set('x', offsetX(point.x))
  panodata.set('y', offsetY(point.y))
  panodata.set('roomModelId', scope.pano.id)
  panodata.set('panoDataRotate', 0)
  panodata.set('differentLayout', false)
  panodata.set('panoCount', 6)
  panodata.set('type', 'VRoom')
  console.log('PANODATA', panodata)
  return panodata
}
```

Why isn't `setPanodata()` visible inside `setPoints()`?

Comment: Because the name is different - it is `setPanodatas` (s at the end) inside `setPoints`, and the function is called `setPanodata`.

Comment: You are calling wrong function name. It should be setPanodata()

Comment: Why are you converting `panodata` to JSON before passing it to the function?

Answer (score 1):

It is because setPanodatas is undefined.
Rather it is setPanodata, you added s.

```
function setPanodata(panodata, point)
```

Comment: Don't waste time posting an answer for such a trivial typo. It was answered in a comment, and the question will be closed soon.

Comment: Oh i see, haven't read that rule about typos, thanks for the info. I think it was the same time i added the answer and then the comments appeared.